# Отображение fieldset и legend в IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Заголовок legend некорректно отображается в ie, нужно так:
[image: Все, кроме IE]

а в IE выходит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.achievements {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    top: 62.7160494%;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 64.6404744%;
    z-index: 200;
   fieldset{
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     width: 28.78440366972477%;
     height: 161px;
     border: 2px solid white;
     legend img {
         margin: 0 5px;
       }
     b {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size:35px;
       color: white;
     }
     p {
       font-size: 20px;
       color: white;
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: без flex box попробуйте ... сработает корректно http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Странно, остальные флексбоксы нормально отображаются, может дело не в них.

Comment: точно не скажу .. но сами видите что flex в ie11 поддерживается с натягом

Comment: ну и только что заметил , у вас в legend img стоит margin: 0 5px; это значит что оно сдвинется на 0 сверху а с права и лева 5px

Comment: ну да, так и есть в других браузерах как на картинке.

Comment: 0 auto поставьте для img и не забудьте display:block; либо inline-block - напиши если не получится

Comment: не пошло, отступы вообще убрались, а там они должны быть, чтобы не было слитно.

Comment: давайте в тем вивер ? я посмотрю что не так

Comment: та у меня его и нет. я как-то что-то решу.